# Django: Cast CharField to Integer if possible

Tags: django, python-3.x, exception, django-models

I have the following code to cast a field `my_field` into integer for sorting.

```
self.object_list = self.object_list.annotate(order_field=Cast('my_field', IntegerField())) \
                                   .order_by('order_field')
```

The problem is that some data fields may be non-numeric, due to which it throws an error. Is there a way to `Cast` only if possible?

I am looking for two cases -

1. Return the full `object_list`, ordering those which are possible and keeping the others in the front/end.
2. Return only the `object_list` where `my_field` can be casted to integer

Answer (score 2):

> Is there a way to Cast only if possible

You can try using [extra](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/querysets/#extra):

```
self.object_list.extra(
    where=[
       "ISNUMERIC(my_field) = 1"
    ]
).annotate(
    order_field=Cast('my_field', IntegerField())
).order_by('order_field')
```

This will solve your (2) requirement and to get (1) done you can use same query with changing `where` to `select` (see docs) to annotate with something like `is_numeric` flag and then order by `order_field` and `is_numeric`.

Comment: Using postgres, getting the following error `function isnumeric(character varying) does not exist`. Still thanks for giving me the right idea, doing the regex match works.

Comment: Yes, sorry, this will work for MySQL. And yes, I see that for PostgreSQL numeric checks are done mostly with regex so good luck with this! :)